# Unable to run hbase shell in Mac

Tags: hbase, jruby, hbase-shell

I have installed zookeeper and Hbase and started the Hbase. And its running i can able to view the web UI.

When i started to intract with it by hbase shell, i can't able to connect to hbase shell

```
HBase Shell
Use "help" to get list of supported commands.
Use "exit" to quit this interactive shell.
For Reference, please visit: http://hbase.apache.org/2.0/book.html#shell
Version 2.5.7, r6788f98356dd70b4a7ff766ea7a8298e022e7b95, Thu Dec 14 15:59:16 PST 2023
Took 0.0000 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                   
NotImplementedError: fstat unimplemented unsupported or native support failed to load; see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Native-Libraries
  initialize at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1015
        open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1156
  initialize at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/input-method.rb:141
  initialize at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/context.rb:70
  initialize at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb.rb:410
  initialize at uri:classloader:/irb/hirb.rb:50
      <main> at classpath:/jar-bootstrap.rb:225
```

this error occuring.

HBase Version : 2.5.7
Jave Version  : 11

Comment: The error message points to https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Native-Libraries which contains a section regarding `NotImplementedError: fstat ...`.

Comment: I don't get it bro thats why im asking here  

```If you get the failure NotImplementedError: fstat unimplemented unsupported or native support failed to load

If you proceed to run it with -Djruby.native.verbose=true and it says java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to execute or load jffi binary stub from /tmp. Set TMPDIR or Java property java.io.tmpdir to a read/write path that is not mounted "noexec". jffi...so  failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted then [see here] for more information```

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably,the issue was addressed only in HBase versions 2.6.0 and 3.0.0-alpha-3. As a workaround, I downloaded the latest HBase 3.0.0 release and specifically extracted the jruby JAR, found at lib/ruby/jruby-complete-9.3.4.0.jar. [As mention in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367316/hbase-shell-error-on-m1-macos-fat-file-but-missing-compatible-architecture-ha/76241995#76241995)

To apply the fix to my current HBase installation (version 2.5.7), I replaced the existing jruby JAR located at [hbase-root-dir]/lib/ruby with the one from the newer version. This resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Note that JRuby 9.2 and 9.3 are both unsupported now. You should really be using JRuby 9.4, preferably the [latest version](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/releases) (currently 9.4.5.0).